# Good jQuery advocacy materials (videos) suitable for a manager?

Tags: jquery

Can anyone recommend any particularly compelling propoganda (papers or even better, video) on jQuery that would be suitable for a manager who knows very little about the technology?

My manager seems very reluctant to consider letting us use it, seeming to think it is yet another technology flavor of the month / flash in the pan.

Comment: Why does the manager care about what technologies you use? Isn't that your job to decide as a developer / architect?..... Seriously, keep the managers where they should be.

Comment: Show him the tag counts in stack overflow to explain how "supported" it is.

Comment: If you show a Manager that something got "16 000" _Questions_ he will only see "Oh my god does 16 000 peope have problem with this?! Then we can definetly NOT use this technology!!".

Comment: @Earlz: I love using the tag counts as a metric.  You know it's likely to stay when the tag count exceeds SQL.

Comment: @Filip, I really hope his manager has some sort of common sense.

Comment: @Earlz, if he demands proof from a (professional) developer on a techonlogy he / she wants to use, I doubt he has that.

Comment: "Why does the manager care about what technologies you use?"  Yes, exactly what I asked myself.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start taking him to sites that use JQuery.  There are several listed on the JQuery site.  Show him results that can be obtained with JQuery and how cool they are.  Then pick some classic asp.NET sites that look and function like garbage.  Compare.  He'll come around.

```
  Google
  Amazon
  Microsoft
  Dell
  Bank of America
```

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx

It's going to be built into Visual Studio from now on, if you don't do MS stuff that probably won't help, but it's a big propaganda boost!

Answer (score 1):

if your manager requires to go into what is clearly not his position, just give him / her a link to [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com/)

> jQuery is a fast and concise
>   JavaScript Library that simplifies
>   HTML document traversing, event
>   handling, animating, and Ajax
>   interactions for rapid web
>   development. jQuery is designed to
>   change the way that you write
>   JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest approaching your manager with evidence along the following lines:

- jQuery is included with Visual Studio and has a huge development community
- JavaScript libraries reduce the amount of code necessary to achieve client-side behavior

You might also list some of the high-profile jQuery users found on jquery.com.

If your manager is technical, consider showing him/her a comparison of plain JavaScript and jQuery to achieve a common task - the jQuery will be much smaller and easier to read/maintain.

Answer (score 1):

[**Sites using JQuery**](http://docs.jquery.com/Sites_Using_jQuery)

- GOogle
- Amazon
- Microsoft
- Twitter
- Dell
- Bank of America
- ....

[**jquery.com/about**](http://jquery.org/about) has a video with John Resig outlining the future of the Project.

Answer (score 1):

If he is calling it a 'flavor of the month / flash in the pan' explain that it is not its own technology like WPF, Silverlight, Flash, etc.

It is simply a very powerful JavaScript library to use while working with JavaScript the same way C# developers use the .Net framework when writing C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help much, but you could try showing them this post from ScottGu:

[jQuery and Microsoft](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx)

Explaining that jQuery is baked in to Visual Studio and ASP.NET...it'll at least get them over the hurdle that it's the flavor of the month (if Microsoft is including it, you can be pretty sure it's not going anywhere for a while).